# Export correlation table in Excel from SAS

Tags: sas, export, correlation

I am trying to export the results of the Correlation table from SAS. However, the exported file only contains r without p-values and n for each variable. I wonder if I am missing anything from SAS. thanks!

```
proc corr data=one Spearman OUTS=spear_corr1;
var v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9;
ODS OUTPUT SpearmanCorr = SPEAR_CORR11;
RUN;
```

Comment: The dataset SPEAR_CORR11 should have p-values and n for each variable. Do you not see them in yours?

Comment: `SPEAR_CORR11` definitely has this information.